# Convert Map<TipoQuestionario, Map<AvaliadorEventoDTO, List<EventoQuestaoDTO>>> to Object EventoAvaliacaoDTO

Tags: java, lambda, lombok

I have a `Map<TipoQuestionario, Map<AvaliadorEventoDTO, List<EventoQuestaoDTO>>>` and I would like to transform it into an object EventoAvaliacaoDTO.

My object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EventoAvaliacaoDTO {

    private TipoQuestionario tipoQuestionario;
    private AvaliadorEventoDTO avaliadorEventoDTO;
    private List<EventoQuestaoDTO> eventoQuestoesDTO;
    
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: "I have a Map<TipoQuestionario, Map<AvaliadorEventoDTO, List>> and I would like to transform it into an object." Good news: it already is one.

Comment: sorry, object EventoAvaliacaoDTO

Comment: If you meant that you want *an instance of the class that you showed*, then you need to be much more specific: is this your class, or someone else's? If it's your own, why not create a constructor for it? In any case, what is the rule that tells you how the `tipoQuestionario` etc. values should be determined?

Comment: It already has a constructor, I use lombock to receive @AllArgsConstructor arguments. But I need to get the values to pass to the constructor, however as there is a Map inside another Map I would like to know how I can do this...

Comment: Okay, so the idea is that you will use a key from the map to populate `tipoQuestionario`, and then the value (which is also a map) will populate `avaliadorEventoDTO` and `eventoQuestoesDTO`? Okay, but what if any of these maps have more than one key-value pair?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to flatten each `TipoQuestionario, AvaliadorEventoDTO` combination to its own object, you can do something like this:

```
Map<TipoQuestionario, Map<AvaliadorEventoDTO, List<EventoQuestaoDTO>>> map = ...
List<EventoAvaliacaoDTO> list = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e2 -> new EventoAvaliacaoDTO(e.getKey(), e2.getKey(), e2.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```